# Convert Java Timestamp Datatype to Scala TimestampType

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, casting, timestamp

Is it possible to cast/convert a Java Timestamp Datatype to Scala TimestampType and vice-versa ?

I tried doing so this way:

`val t = <Java Timestamp variable>.asInstanceOf[TimestampType]`

But got this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.sql.Timestamp cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType
```

Comment: What is your end goal for such casting? Can you give more expanded explanation of the problem?

Comment: @BorisAzanov I'm trying to see if writing my program in Spark native language would improve performance. So I am trying my best to use the least/no Java code.

Comment: If you provide more concrete code example maybe I would help you improve it and make more safety.

Answer (score 2):

In Spark `org.apache.spark.sql.types.Timestamp` - is subclass of `abstract class DataType`. All such subclasses is like just meta-information types of `DataFrame` columns. They doesn't contain some value but `java.sql.Timestamp` does it. And they are not subclasses, that is the reason you can't cast it using `asInstanceOf`.

Give you a small example to feel the difference:

when you just store data into `DataFrame` Spark will cast it by itself to `spark.Timestamp`

```
import java.sql.Timestamp    

val t = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())
val dfA: DataFrame = Seq(
  ("a", t),
  ("b", t),
  ("c", t)
).toDFc"key", "time")
```

but if you want to read data and get `java.Timestamp` you can do it so:

```
dfA.collect().foreach{
  row =>
    println(row.getAs[Timestamp](1))
} 
// will prints 
2020-07-31 00:45:48.825
2020-07-31 00:45:48.825
2020-07-31 00:45:48.825
```

if you will look at `DataFrame` schema:

```
dfA.printSchema()
dfA.schema.fields.foreach(println)
```

it will prints:

```
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- time: timestamp (nullable = true)

StructField(key,StringType,true)
StructField(time,TimestampType,true)
```

but if you will try to cast java.Timestamp using `asInctanceOf` you will get fairly error:

```
println(t.asInstanceOf[TimestampType]) 
/*
java.sql.Timestamp incompatible with 
    org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType java.lang.ClassCastException: java.sql.Timestamp incompatible with org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType
/*
```